# Oracle: Scopes of the CURSOR_SHARING parameter

Tags: oracle

In Oracle databases (12.2 and above), is it possible to configure the CURSOR_SHARING parameter differently for different schemas, tables or views, or is that parameter always global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle recommends *not* using cursor_sharing=force as a permanent solution to latch contention. See here in the documentation for details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/improving-rwp-cursor-sharing.html#GUID-7FF4E133-06A7-401E-9BFC-3B0B9C902346 There are both security and performance implications for doing so.

That said, there are a few cases where you're dealing with 3rd party applications (i.e. you can't change the source code) and there's a lot of near duplicate SQL being generated and it is causing problems with latch contention, etc. In that case, the recommendation is to set cursor_sharing=force at the session level using a logon trigger for a specific user, like this for user "pmdba":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PMDBA_LOGON_TRG 
AFTER LOGON ON PMDBA.SCHEMA 
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'alter session set cursor_sharing=force';
END;
/
```

If cursor_sharing happens to be set to "force" by whatever means, you can use a hint to turn it off on a statement-by-statement basis, like this:

```
SELECT /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ hostname FROM servers WHERE srvr_id = 3;
```

There is no statement level hint to turn cursor_sharing on to "force" when the session or system level setting is "exact", and there is no way to make cursor_sharing an object level property.

Also see this blog posts for more information:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables

Answer (score 2):

You can create LOGON TRIGGER ON SCHEMA and use

```
execute immediate 'alter session set CURSOR_SHARING=...';
```

to set it on session level